# NS-3.25 PyViz visualizer install on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, python

I'm installing `Network Simulator 3.25` on a `CentOS 6.5` machine.

In my environment I cannot use any repository, every single packet have to be downloaded from a machine and then transferred to the others.

I have two version of `python` : 2.6 and 2.7.
`NS-3` `./configuration` uses the 2.6 one.

I'm building NS-3 with `waf` and so far I had no issue other than with PyViz visualizer.

In particular I can't get rid of

> (Missing python modules: gtk, goocanvas)

Initially even `pygraphviz module` was missing but installing the right packages solved it. So I expected the same result from gtk and goocanvas but it's not the case. (If i use python 2.7 also pygraphviz module` is missing)

I tried both with source files and rpms but `NS-3` `./configuration` still can't find them. Both modules are in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple ... there was a mismatch between some libraries. In particular, reinstalling `gtk2-2.20.1-4` packet (`libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` was causing some trouble) did the trick.

The issue was found testing pygtk-demo :

> undefined symbol: gdk_pixbuf_format_get_type

Now NS-3 is detecting all packages correctly and I was able to install PyViz visualizer module